# Can a red-black tree have a black node with a single black child?

Tags: tree, red-black-tree

When describing the deletion procedure for red-black trees, Arge and Lagoudakis focus on the case when the node to be deleted is black and has a single black child (illustrated in Figure 16 of the CP230 lecture notes [here](https://courses.cs.duke.edu/cps130/fall02/fall02lectures/lecture18/long_redblack.pdf) and reproduced below):

[image: Figure 16 from Arge and Lagoudakis (2002)]

However, following the description given on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) (which follows CLRS), it would seem that a node with a single black child would also have a black NIL (leaf) node as its other child. This would immediately create root-leaf paths in a red-black tree that contain different numbers of black nodes. Those that go from the root to the NIL node would have one less than those that go through the child. So it would seem to me that the case considered by Arge and Lagoudakis could never arise.  So my question is: *can a red-black tree have a black node with a single black child?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re completely right that a black node in a red-black tree can’t have exactly one black child. My understanding - which may be incorrect - is that the algorithm they are describing for deletion contains a case where a black node with no children can be pushed higher up into the tree. (The idea is to either fix the violation locally or to push the violation up toward the root where it can easily be dealt with.) In the course of doing so, it’s possible that the black node being pushed higher up might end up having exactly one black child. By defining this case as “the black node has zero children or one black child,” the logic here can be applied recursively to move the node upward, even if the node couldn’t initially begin with one black child.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I think your interpretation is essentially correct. 
  
Adding a note here for future readers: Having gone back through the CLRS chapter on Red-Black Tree deletion, it appears that Arge and Lagoudakis use the "black node with single black child" as an alternative representation that roughly corresponds to the "double black" node employed by CLRS. This leads to a similar overall approach, but a few extra cases have to be handled explicitly (this is in part because they do not make use of the red-and-black node representation used by CLRS).

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right in your analysis: in a valid red-black tree, if a node has just one child node, that child node cannot be black. It doesn't even matter what the colour is of the first mentioned node. The reasoning you gave remains the same, and is correct.

The cited document obscures that a red-back tree is a binary tree where each node has exactly **two** pointers -- and that their order is significant (one is "left", the other is "right") -- by depicting some edges *vertically*, as if there is no second pointer.

Also the Wikipedia article on the subject confirms in the section [Removal: simple cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Removal:_simple_cases) that it is not valid for a node with just one child, to have a black child:

> If **N** has exactly one non-NIL child, it must be a red child, because if it were a black one then requirement 4<sup>*</sup> would force a second black non-NIL child.
>
> ---
>
> <sub><sup>*</sup>4. Every path from a given node to any of its descendant NIL nodes goes through the same number of black nodes.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No a red black tree cannot have a black node with a single black child.

A black node can have

- 0 children
- 1 child which is red
- 2 black children
- 2 red children
- 2 children made up of a black child and a red child which
  itself has 2 black children

All of this is to ensure that for any given node, the count of real black nodes (i.e. not NIL nodes counted as black) is the same for every path, one of the 4 rules of red-black trees)

Answer (score -2):

The root of the tree is always black. There are no two adjacent red nodes (A red node cannot have a red parent or red child). Every path from a node (including root) to any of its descendants NULL nodes has the same number of black nodes.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The asker is well aware of what you write.